# Looking for info on how to change the settings on a scheduled task from powershell

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

I have some PowerShell scripts which are being ran daily using a scheduled task, the scheduled task is created using PowerShell itself and is all working quite nicely.

Id like to be able to add a setting into the scheduled task as follows:-

I want to be able to change the setting -> Stop the task if it runs longer than 3 days.

Can I change this setting somehow, I've managed to create the scheduled task in PowerShell and I can change the triggers, actions and so on but I cant see how to affect the Settings, without manually changing them inside task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

**help from the below link:**

http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2013/06/21/changing-scheduled-tasks-with-powershell.aspx

**Solution:**

```
$service = New-Object -ComObject Schedule.Service

# Can connect remotely as well, currently doing it local

$service.Connect($env:COMPUTERNAME)

# navigate to desired folder where the scheduled task is in TaskScheduler

$folder = $service.GetFolder('\Microsoft\Windows\XXX_DestinationFolder_XXX')

# Get the desired task

$task = $folder.GetTask('XXX_TaskName_XXX')

$definition = $task.Definition

# Incase you are interested in changing more settings

# $definition | Get-Member

# for 10 days it is 'P10D', by default it is 3 days so it will be 'P3D'

$definition.Settings | Where-Object {$_.ExecutionTimeLimit = 'P10D'}

# finally updating

$folder.RegisterTaskDefinition($task.Name, $definition, 4, $null, $null, $null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to PowerShell 4.0 or later, you can use [ScheduledTask CMDlets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649816(v=wps.630).aspx) to create/update them. Here is an example for changing the Time Limit:

```
$STSet = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -ExecutionTimeLimit 72:00:00
Set-ScheduledTask ScheduledTaskName -Settings $STSet
```